# Rav Ovadiah and talking in a shul or beis medrash delays the Geulah

Tags: halacha, synagogue, messiah, speech-talking

Rav Ovadiah zt”l says, “Talking in a *shul* or *beis medrash* (during tefillah) delays the *Geulah*.”

He bring it down in the *Yabe’ah Omer* 1:10:11. I don't know what what 1:10:11 stands for.
Can someone send me a direct link of where this is located?

Comment: I bet we can find you "sinning delays the redemption". Is that sufficient?

Comment: Isn't that a [Miami song](http://alljewishlyrics.blogspot.co.il/2009/07/dont-talk.html)?

Comment: @DoubleAA - one could counter that not all talking in shul is a sin; sometimes it's a Mitzva - like being nice / friendly / helpful  to somebody - as long as it's not during those sections when one is forbidden from talking.

Comment: @DannySchoemann I agree. And whatever source anyone finds is not going to prohibit those things.

Comment: -1 for changing question after answers were recorded

Comment: My guess is that "Yabe’ah Omer 1:10:11" stands for Vol. 1, Ch. 10 Siman 11. -1 for changing question after answers were recorded.

Answer (score 3):

[Moreh Mikdash](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=3725&st=%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9D+%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9F&pgnum=3) brings the following in the name of the Zohar Parshas Achrei Mos. There are 3 things that lengthen our time in Galus. One of them is "She'osim Kolon B'shechina B'galus". The Zohar in Parshas Teruma says that one who speaks in Shul is "Gorem Kolon L'shechina". Thus one who talks in Shul vain talk is lengthening the Galus.

Comment: So cheering up somebody who looks glum, during Gelila (for example), lengthens the Golus. Interesting....

Comment: @DannySchoemann: That is not vain talk.

Comment: I missed the "vain" word, as I was referring to the OP:  “Talking in a shul or beis medrash (during tefillah) delays the Geulah.”

Answer (score 2):

Mainstream Halacha (Rambam, Shulchan Aruch and similar) clearly forbids talking during certain parts of the prayer service - like during the Amida.

Other times they permit talking under certain circumstances - like during Shma if one needs to answer a person one fears.

Other times talking is technically permitted. If `talking in a shul or beis medrash (during tefillah) delays the Geulah`, then surely the Poskim would have mentioned this - at least as a Chumra or a good idea.

Furthermore, one could argue that **not** ever talking during tefillah delays the Geulah. Sometimes being friendly to a newcomer, or helping a person with a problem, or passing on relevant - timely - information is a Mitzva of "Love your fellow Jew".

Often people don't understand (nor appreciate) mimes, especially when they're trying to concentrate in praying. A few well chosen words are often worth a thousand hand signals.

The Geula is being delayed - IIRC - because of Sinat Chinam - which is the flip side of VeAhavta leRe'acha. So not talking in shul may sometimes delay the Geula.

That said, as DoubleAA already pointed out, **needless talking** in a shul or beis medrash is often a sign of disrespect for the place, and any sin could potentially delay the geula. Especially since a shul or beis medrash is a Mikdash Me'at - and if we don't respect those, we can hadly be worthy of the rebuilding of the real Mikdash.

Comment: "_Other times talking is technically permitted. If `talking in a shul or beis medrash (during tefillah) delays the Geulah`, then surely the Poskim would have mentioned this - at least as a Chumra or a good idea_" ....don't mean to insult, but do you feel you really know what _all_ poskim have written on the subject?

Comment: @Shokhet: I already defined that as "Rambam, Shulchan Aruch and similar". IIRC they don't mention it, and nor does the bet Yosef, who tends to bring "everything' on the subject.

Comment: Fair enough. (just making the point that there may be other things out there).

Comment: I typically narrow the definition of Poskim, since recently there have been so many Seforim published that I have the feeling that one can find almost every opinion (valid or not) on almost any subject.

Comment: Danny Schoemann, you must realize that hilchos tefillah is a meis mitzvah just as much as hilchos sheimos.

Comment: Just to make it perfectly clear: I am against talking during Davening, and I am very unpopular in Shul, as I often tell people to be quiet.